# Jenkins выдает ошибку на docker.image("${env.IMAGENAME}:${env.LAST_COMMIT_TAG}").remove(message: "Removing outdated image")

Tags: docker, jenkins

Вот часть моего пайпа
'''

```
    stage('build') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.build("${env.IMAGENAME}:${env.LAST_COMMIT_TAG}")
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Deploy image') {
        steps {
            script{
                docker.withRegistry(IMAGEHUBURL , CREDENTIALDOCKERHUB) {
                    docker.image("${env.IMAGENAME}:${env.LAST_COMMIT_TAG}").push()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Delete docker image locally') {
        steps{
            docker.image("${env.IMAGENAME}:${env.LAST_COMMIT_TAG}").remove(message: "Removing outdated image")
        }
    }
```

'''

ошибка

"org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 237: Expected a symbol @ line 237, column 17.
docker.image("${env.IMAGENAME}:${env.LAST_COMMIT_TAG}").remove(message: "Removing outdated image")
^

1 error

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1107)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox$Scope.parse(GroovySandbox.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:190)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:175)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:568)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:518)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:336)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```

Finished: FAIL"

Ругается он именно на docker.image().remove().В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После некоторых поисков на свежую голову понял,что последний стэйдж должен выглядеть так:

```
stage('Delete docker image locally') {
        steps{
            sh "docker rmi ${env.IMAGENAME}:${env.LAST_COMMIT_TAG}"
        }
    }
```